# How to shift 1st column to the last in a Kendo UI hierarchical grid.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a kendo UI hierarchical grid, where I have to display the expand icon for each row to the end instead of in a 1st column. Is there a setting available which can be set to true to achieve this? If not then how to do this. I could not find any suggestion or working example over the net.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible out of the box. But you can do a workaround using jQuery.

```
dataBound: function() {
    var headerRow = $(".k-grid-header").find("tr[role='row']");
    $(".k-grid-header").find(".k-hierarchy-cell").detach().appendTo(headerRow);
    var trs = $(".k-grid-content").find("tr.k-master-row");
    $(".k-grid-content").find(".k-hierarchy-cell").each(function(i) {
        $(this).detach().appendTo(trs[i]);
    });
}
```

An example on [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UKuku).

Comment: Thanks! I created a directive based on your answer, since I had to use it in multiple pages.

Comment: The solution really worked. Only thing that could be added on here is, that you need to detach the first cell `colgroup`  from both the header and table body  and append it as the last cell.